# How to build the simple change maker for a vending machine?

Tags: c++

On the menu deposits n,d, q, o,f are indicated which are indication for nickel dime quarter , one dollar and five dollar. I should also indicate "C" as in cancel option when the user hits c. But i couldn't make it work. My program still runs even the user hit c. I am confused on this point?

```
switch(DepositIndication) {
    case 'n': {
        PurchasedPrice=PurchasedPrice-0.05;
        NumOfNickels=NumOfNickels+1;
    }
    break;
    case 'd': {
        PurchasedPrice=PurchasedPrice-0.10;
        NumOfdimes=NumOfdimes+1;
    }
    break;
    case 'q': {
        PurchasedPrice=PurchasedPrice-0.25;
        NumOfquarters=NumOfquarters+1;
    }
    break;
    case 'o': {
        PurchasedPrice=PurchasedPrice-1.00;
        NumOfOnes=NumOfOnes+1;
    }
    break;
    case 'f': {
        PurchasedPrice=PurchasedPrice-5.00;
        NumOfFives=NumOfFives+1;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: @MathewHD Isn't this a matter of style? (I prefer the `break;` outside of curly brackets.) However, this definitely doesn't change the semantic of that `switch()` statement.

Comment: Thanks I didn't' even know you could put the breaks outside of the cases.

Comment: @MathewHD The `switch()` of C/C++ isn't like in other languages (although it might look like). It's more like a "conditional goto". Hence, you have much freedom where to put the `case`s, and you can group them, and you may not forget to insert the `break`s (except you _want_ a "fall through").

Comment: Yeah I know you have to add the break from other languages like C# which is my main programming language. But thanks for the information :D

Answer (score 0):

the condition c is missing and I Put the break into to brackets;

```
switch (DepositIndication) {
    case 'n':
        {

            PurchasedPrice = PurchasedPrice - 0.05;
            NumOfNickels = NumOfNickels + 1;

            break;
        }
    case 'd':
        {
            PurchasedPrice = PurchasedPrice - 0.10;
            NumOfdimes = NumOfdimes + 1;
            break;
        }
    case 'q':
        {
            PurchasedPrice = PurchasedPrice - 0.25;
            NumOfquarters = NumOfquarters + 1;

            break;
        }
    case 'o':
        {
            PurchasedPrice = PurchasedPrice - 1.00;
            NumOfOnes = NumOfOnes + 1;
            break;
        }
    case 'f':
        {
            PurchasedPrice = PurchasedPrice - 5.00;
            NumOfFives = NumOfFives + 1;
            break;
        }
    case 'c':
        } 
        //you can print cancellation messages in here
        break;
        }

    default:
        break;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I should also indicate "C" as in cancel option when the user hits c

Your current code works fine the only thing you are missing to make that work right now is a default case or a case where you specifically check if the user inputed C.

**Example:**

```
switch(DepositIndication) {
    // All other cases ...
    case 'c': {
        // The user canceled the interaction
        std::cout << "Interaction was canceled." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    // Default case to ensure that even, 
    // if the user hits any other key we still handle his interaction
    default {
        std::cout << "No fitting interactional behaviour found." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to ensure that the user can even input big lettered chars and the switch case will still work you can use `std::tolower` and cast it back to a char.

**Make the User-Input lowercase:**

```
// Make DepositIndication lowercase
DepositIndication = std::tolower(DepositIndication, std::locale());
```